# Center page middle of the page, from top and from left

Tags: html, css

Simple question. I want my page to be in the middle, both from the top and from left.

Just point out what I need to add and where, thank you. If you see some error in the css, please correct that too.

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* Created By CaptainMcMarcus */
/* Heavily customized by Sjokomelk */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600);

html {
    height: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* Clearing some default browser settings */
* {border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
a:active {outline:none;}
:focus {-moz-outline-style:none;}
.clear {clear:both;}

/* These parts can be easily changed to affect the design */
body {color: #FFF; font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed;}

p {text-align: justify; font-size:16px;}
p a { text-decoration: underline; color: #ea5353; text-decoration: underline;}
p a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #333;}

/* Core Wrapper which we vertically align */
.wrapper {width: 700px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;}

.box-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.box-wrap h2 {width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 15px 0; text-align: center; 
background: url('images/header-bg.png') repeat center top; background-color: RGBA(42,52,59,0.75);}

.box-wrap p {font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; padding: 15px 30px; overflow: hidden; 
text-align: justify; width: 640px; height: auto; background: #ffffff; color: #717171;}

.icon-box {width: 210px; height: 210px; background: #FFF; margin: 20px 15px 20px 0; float: left; text-decoration: none;}
.icon-box a {text-decoration: none;}
.icon-box p {font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 22px; text-align: center; color: #717171; text-decoration: none;}

.icon-box:hover {background: #f1f1f1;}

.wide {width: 700px; margin: 0px;}
.end2 {margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}

.end {margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;}

nav {margin: 10px auto; width: 700px;}
    nav ul {width: 700px; height: auto; list-style: none; float: left; padding:0;}
    nav ul li a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #717171;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 0;
    width: 105px;
    margin: 0px 14px 0 0;
    }
nav ul li{ position:relative; float:left;}
nav ul li a:hover {background: #f1f1f1;}

nav ul li:last-child a{
margin-right:0;
}

nav ul li ul.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    display:none;
    top: 35px;
}
nav ul > li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}

code, pre {
  padding: 0 3px 2px;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}
code {
  padding: 3px 4px;
  color: #d14;
  background-color: #f7f7f9;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
}
pre {
  display: block;
  padding: 8.5px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

pre code {
  padding: 0;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.footer h3 {width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 15px 0; text-align: center; 
background: url('images/header-bg.png') repeat center top; background-color: RGBA(42,52,59,0.75);}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta name="description" content="Forside" /> 
    <title>Hjortefjellet</title> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script><!-- Link to jquery so we can center the content -->

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="wrapper"><!-- Opens the wrapper so we can contain and center everything -->

   <img src="images/logo.png" width="702" height="87" alt="Your Logo" />

      <nav>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HJEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="forum">FORUM</a></li>
        <li><a href="doner.html">DONER</a></li>
        <li><a href="servere.html">SERVERE</a>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a style="margin-right: 0 !important;" href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a></li>
  </ul>
      </nav>

        <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="box-wrap">
            <h2>Velkommen til Hjortefjellet</h2>

            <p class="text-box"><!-- PAGE TEXT -->
            Hjortefjellet er et nytt norsk gaming coummunity som har brukeroplevelsen i fokus. Vi startet opp 21. februar og har nå en Garry's Mod som kjører Trouble in Terrorist Town. Ta gjerne turen innom for å bli bedre kjent med oss.</p>
            <p class="text-box">Has albucius oporteat eu, eos eu etiam intellegam. Has posse dicant feugiat ut, cu quo case convenire definitionem, possim persius meliore no est. Urbanitas vituperatoribus eos in, pro delenit reformidans eu. Nec detracto sadipscing te.</p>

        </div>

        <div class="footer">
          <h3>© Hjortefjellet.com 2014 | Siden benytter cookies</h3>
        </div>

    </div><!-- This closes the wrapper -->



    </body><!-- Closes off the HTML Document -->
</html>
```

Again, thank you.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. Did you fix it? If you did, you need to delete this post so no one thinks this is still a problem

Comment: @lotusms I only got it from left to right, not centered from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much wrong with your code. Your base-box, which is your content wrapper, seems to be centered correctly. Defining a vertical center depends on a height. If you give your page a height=auto, you won't be able to center it because the parent height is not defined. (not without JQuery anyway)

I added a min-height to your wrapper to show that you have a centered base-box. If you want to center the text vertically. Encase it in a div or use `<br>` to separate the paragraphs and then give it a specific top and bottom margin. *Unhide the css line I commented out

[***HERE'S YOUR CODE***](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/ex9ue/1/)